# how to write e2e test automation for application containing kafka, postgres, and rest api docker containers

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, docker-compose, end-to-end

I have an app which is setup by docker-compose. The app contains docker containers for kafka, postgres, rest api endpoints.

One test case is to post data to endpoints. In the data, there is a field called `callback URL`. the app will parse the data and send the data to the `callback URL`.

I am curious whether there is any test framework for similar test cases. and how to verify the `callback URL` is hit with data?

Answer (score 1):

Docker compose support has been added to [endly](https://github.com/viant/endly/blob/master/system/docker/service_contract.go). In the pipeline workflow for the app (app.yaml), you can add a "deploy" task and start the docker services by invoking docker-compose up.

Once test task is completed and your callback url is invoked, in your validation task, you can check to see if it was invoked with the expected data. For this you can utilize endly's [recording feature and replay](https://github.com/viant/endly/blob/master/testing/endpoint/http/service_contract.go) it to validate the callback request.

Below is an example of an ETL application app.yaml using docker-compose with endly to start the docker services. Hope it helps.

```
tasks: $tasks
defaults:
  app: $app
  version: $version
  sdk: $sdk
  useRegistry: false
pipeline:
  build:
    name: Build GBQ ETL
    description: Using a endly shared workflow to build
    workflow: app/docker/build
    origin:
      URL: ./../../
      credentials: localhost
    buildPath: /tmp/go/src/etl/app
    secrets:
      github: git
    commands:
      - apt-get -y install git
      - export GOPATH=/tmp/go
      - export GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=1
      - cd $buildPath
      - go get -u .
      - $output:/Username/? ${github.username}
      - $output:/Password/? ${github.password}
      - export CGO_ENABLED=0
      - go build -o $app
      - chmod +x $app
    download:
      /$buildPath/${app}: $releasePath
      /$buildPath/startup.sh: $releasePath
      /$buildPath/docker-entrypoint.sh: $releasePath
      /$buildPath/VERSION: $releasePath
      /$buildPath/docker-compose.yaml: $releasePath
  deploy:
    start:
      action: docker:composeUp
      target: $target
      source:
        URL: ${releasePath}docker-compose.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

In your question below, where is Kafka involved? Both sound like HTTP calls.

1)Post data to endpoint

2)Against send data to the callback URL

> *One test case is to post data to endpoints. In the data, there is a field called callback URL. the app will parse the data and send the data to the callback URL.*

Assuming the callback URL is an HTTP endpoint(e.g. REST or SOAP) with POST/PUT api, then it's better to expose a GET endpoint on the same resource. In that case, when callback POST/PUT is invoked, the server side state/data changes and next, use the GET api to verify the data is correct. The output of the GET API is the Kafka data which was sent to the callback URL(*this assumes your 1st post message was to a kafka topic*).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using traditional JUnit way using bit of code or via declarative way where you can completely bypass coding.

> The example has dockerized Kafka containers to bring up locally and run the tests

This section [Kafka with REST APIs](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/wiki/Kafka-Testing-Introduction#6--combining-kafka-testing-with-rest-api-testing) explains automated way of testing combination of REST api testing with Kafka data streams .

e.g.

```yaml
---
scenarioName: Kafka and REST api validation example
steps:
- name: produce_to_kafka
  url: kafka-topic:people-address
  operation: PRODUCE
  request:
    recordType: JSON
    records:
    - key: id-lon-123
      value:
        id: id-lon-123
        postCode: UK-BA9
  verify:
    status: Ok
    recordMetadata: "$NOT.NULL"
- name: verify_updated_address
  url: "/api/v1/addresses/${$.produce_to_kafka.request.records[0].value.id}"
  operation: GET
  request:
    headers:
      X-GOVT-API-KEY: top-key-only-known-to-secu-cleared
  verify:
    status: 200
    value:
      id: "${$.produce_to_kafka.request.records[0].value.id}"
      postCode: "${$.produce_to_kafka.request.records[0].value.postcode}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Idaithalam is a low code Test automation Framework,  developed using Java and Cucumber. It leverages Behavior Driven Development (BDD). Tester can create test cases/scripts in simple Excel with API Spec. Excel is a simplified way to create Json based test scripts in Idaithalam. Test cases can be created quickly and tested in minutes.

As a tester, you need to create Excel and pass it to Idaithalam Framework.

First, generate the Json based test scripts(Virtualan Collection) from Excel. During test execution, this test script collection can be directly utilized.

Then it generates Feature files from the Virtualan Collection and its executed.

Lastly, It generates test report in BDD/Cucumber style.

This provide complete testing support for **REST APIs, GraphQL, RDBMS DB and Kafka Event messages**

Refer following link for more information to set up and execute.

https://tutorials.virtualan.io/#/Excel

[How to create test scripts using excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dEKO.png)